# Flink: Declaring dynamic tuple size & type

Tags: java, csv, apache-flink, flink-streaming

Is there any way to declare the various types in the tuple dynamically?

I found a way to declare the number of columns in the Tuple dynamically:

`env.readCsvFile(filePath).tupleType(Tuple.getTupleClass(3))`

But without any type parameters, it throws as error:

`Exception in thread "main" org.apache.flink.api.common.functions.InvalidTypesException: Tuple needs to be parameterized by using generics.`

I wanted to use all the elements in the Tuple as simple `String`. The following works:

`env.readCsvFile(filePath).types(String.class, String.class);`

This results in a `Tuple2(String,String)` type. But in my case, I don't know how many columns of data there is in the csv. But I'm fine reading all the columns as Strings. (I understand that there's limit of max 25 columns)

I even tried reading by specifying the sub-type of `CsvInputFormat`:

`env.readFile(new TupleCsvInputFormat(filePath,TypeInformation.of(String.class), filePath);`

But couldn't get it to compile. Wasn't sure how to use this for my case. I was also unsure on how to extend the Tuple class to achieve the same (if possible). `TypeHint` seems to require me to know the number of columns before-hand.

I'm not sure about the other `env.read...()` methods. I tried a few, but a few methods like `ignoreFirstLine()` were not available. They only come with the `CsvReader`.

So, can someone kindly help me figure out the best approach to read a csv if the number of columns can be arbitrary (passed by input), and to read each element of the `Tuple` as a simple `String`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It possible to write your own method to read CSV files. Maybe something like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    ExecutionEnvironment env = ExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment();
    int n = 3; // number of columns here
    Class[] types = IntStream.range(0, n).mapToObj(i -> String.class).toArray(Class[]::new);
    DataSet<Tuple> csv = readCsv(env, "filename.csv", types);
    csv.print();
}

private static DataSource<Tuple> readCsv(ExecutionEnvironment env, String filename, Class[] fieldTypes) {
    TupleTypeInfo<Tuple> typeInfo = TupleTypeInfo.getBasicAndBasicValueTupleTypeInfo(fieldTypes);
    TupleCsvInputFormat<Tuple> inputFormat = new TupleCsvInputFormat<>(new Path(filename), typeInfo);
    return new DataSource<>(env, inputFormat, typeInfo, Utils.getCallLocationName());
}
```

Note: this method skips calling `configureInputFormat` method in the `CsvReader` class. And if you need it you can do it.

Comment: I loved the usage of `mapToObj`. That was a neat trick. Thanks! :)